# Remove duplicates from an array built in SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ssjs, duplicate-management, array

I'm using SSJS to pull api data and build emails.  I have an array built that has some duplicate data in it.  I'm looking for anyway to remove the duplicate information.  I've tried all the regular JS methods, filter, spread operator, etc... but not seem to the trick.  Does anyone have any experience with or any ideas?

```
var uniqe_mls_array = [...Set new(mls_text_array)]; // Didn't work, can't use new
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work but may be overkill:

```
    var outputArray = [];
    var count = 0;
    var start = false;

for (j = 0; j < mls_text_array.length; j++) {
    for (k = 0; k < outputArray.length; k++) {
        if (mls_text_array[j] == outputArray[k]) {
            start = true;
        }
    }
    count++;
    if (count == 1 && start == false) {
        outputArray.push(mls_text_array[j]);
    }
    start = false;
    count = 0;
}

Variable.SetValue("@mls_text_string", outputArray.toString());
```